# changing bridgehead server post-install in a mixed exchange 2010/2003 environment

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, exchange-migration

We have an Exchange 2003 environment (12 exchange site servers with one co-located bridgehead and a single outbound mail connector).

Recently we have added an exchange 2010 server to the mix at one of our sites. During the  2010 install (not done by me in this case) I gather that the bridgehead server is specified in order to create a new 2003 - 2010 routing group and allow messaging between the two.

All fine so far. I should probably add that I'm not particularly familiar with exchange 2010, so this is quite a journey of discovery.

The issue I'm having: we are busy with a fairly large network migration at the same time, and the bridgehead server being used above is falling away with a new one having been put in place at another (physically connected) facility.

Is it possible - and if so how - to change the remote bridgehead in the newly created (2010-2003) routing group? Attempting to modify the connector in the normal exchange 2003 system manager gives an error about the object not being modifiable in earlier versions of exchange manager, but I have no idea where the same connector setting would be in 2010.

Clearly a re-install would solve all of the above but be a bit of a pain as the server is live and has been in use for a while - is a change of the connector possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right, never mind - found the answer. I can be changed via powershell. for the benefit of anyone else looking:

grab a list of the current routing groups to a file

`get-routinggroupconnector | fl > c:\routegroups.txt`

there will be two groups (one in either direction) - the connector can then be modified using

`set-routinggroupconnector` with the appropriate target bridgeheads...

Comment: Awesome you saved the day! I was looking just for this information. I am leading a migration from 2003 to 2010 in a mixed 2003,2007 and 2010 environment and was just not sure why the routing between 2010 and 2003 was going through 2007... I could have gone nuts had been not for your article as I am not a macho in 2003. Thanks again.